# Kafka - creating producer on Windows IOException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ioexception

I run Apache Kafka on Windows. When I run zookeeper and one broker it is OK. Then I run producer command and everything still is OK. When I run consumer command I get the below error. I have no idea what to do, I'm using 64b JVM.

```
[2018-07-03 11:47:42,978] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error while making broker the leader for partition Topic: __consumer_offsets; Partition: 16; Leader: None; AllReplicas: ; InSyncReplicas:  in dir None (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while creating log for __consumer_offsets-16 in dir c:\tmp\kafka-logs
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:940)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:67)
        at kafka.log.TimeIndex.<init>(TimeIndex.scala:54)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment$.open(LogSegment.scala:561)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:412)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:216)
        at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:1747)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:673)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:641)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:641)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:177)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:173)
        at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:65)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.getOrCreateReplica(Partition.scala:172)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$8.apply(Partition.scala:259)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$8.apply(Partition.scala:259)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$6.apply(Partition.scala:259)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$6.apply(Partition.scala:253)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:250)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:258)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:253)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1165)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1163)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:1163)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1083)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:183)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:108)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:937)
        ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change 32b Java to 64b.

Comment: Looks like I am going through the same issue. "java -version" says I am using 64-bit. How did you change? Is there a configuration in Kafka to point to specific java version?